# java.lang.ClassCastException - Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, classloader, apache-commons-logging

When starting my managed server I see the following ClassCastException related to log4j in my WebLogic 12c managed server out file.   I have commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and log4j-1.2.17.jar bundled in my WAR's lib directory and no other version of those libraries there.  I also pasted the managed server log file error generated in in processing a request.  Should I be using the log4j and commons logging that comes with WebLogic 12c?  I see these in the modules directory: com.bea.core.apache.commons.logging_1.1.2.jar and com.bea.core.apache.log4j_1.2.0.0_1-2-15.jar.  I haven't had a problem with log4j and WebLogic before.

out file:

```
jadomain.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:248)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:176)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:523)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:436)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:1004)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:872)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:778)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.jadomain:906)
        at com.domain.d.app.restwrapper.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.jadomain:37)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.jadomain:66
```

log file:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
jadomain.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.log4j.LogMF.entering(Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;Ljadomain/lang/String;Ljadomain/lang/String;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, com/domain/d/app/restwrapper/appResource, and the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/log4j/LogMF, have different Class objects for the type /lang/String;)V used in the signature
        at com.domain.d.app.restwrapper.appResource.addQuery(appResource.jadomain:244)
        at com.domain.d.app.restwrapper.appResource.addQuery(appResource.jadomain:224)
        at com.domain.d.app.restwrapper.appResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addQuery(appResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.jadomain)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jadomain:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jadomain:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict between tow versions of log4j. One is loaded from the server's classpath and the other one from your web application's classpath.
To resolve it you can setup your web application to use only the one from your application. Update your weblogic.xml file and add the following tag :

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```